# HTML Link Parser: Dynamic Data Extraction in Jmeter

Tags: html, jmeter

I tried HTML link parser to fetch data from a form and for the same form I provided data using CSV file for all the fields except the one for dropdown field in the form:

```
Thread group
-Http request sampler
-->form to fetch by html link parser
-Http request sampler
 -Html link parser
-csv data set config
```

Expected Result: For all fields in form data is dynamilcally fetch from CSV file, except the one dropdown field for which values are fetch from HTML link parser.

[image]

I set the Variable in the “Send parameter as Request” in the request panel accordingly the CSV file:

[image]

I use the value parsed using the HTML Link Parser .
Just put [.*] excluding the braces as the “Value” to the Dropdown field name in the request panel

Comment: Please clarify again what scenario steps you are trying to automate, What is your current script (a screenshot will be good). and what issue you are facing. Please try to divide in separate sections for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks for response i added a script pic